# Private keys for mainnet vs testnet

Tags: private-key, testnet

If I have valid private key to use on Bitcoin mainnet, can I use the same key to generate addresses and spend on testnet? If so, is this encouraged, or should one generally keep separate keys to use on mainnet and testnet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. A valid private key can be used either on testnet and mainnet. But key reuse is never a good thing, even within the same chain. Just use two different wallets, it's free!